# How to get the most used(popular) tags in the Instagram API?

Tags: android, json, api, instagram-api

How do I get the most used or popular tags from the Instagram API? I searched the API but I couldn't find how to do so. I have seen many Android Apps and websites that do that. However, the closest endpoint I found to get the most popular tags is this one https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=snowy&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so......You can use `GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent` to find the most recently posted media with that tag, and larger returns would lead you to the most used. Yes, that is time consuming, but if you've done some research beforehand you should have a narrowed down list of tags. And there is a new Instagram Graph API that looks like it is designed for business information, details at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/. I have not used it, but perhaps it will give you some additional guidance. If you'd like more information and tutorials on the Instagram API, you can check out this [wiki link](https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Instagram+API).